# Resume Key adds New Line Instead of Sending Message

Tags: java, android

I have this code for triggering the enter key for sending messages. I am testing now my app with Pixel XL and instead of sending message as normal phones do, it adds new line for some reason. Any ideas how to overcome this nonsense?

```
 edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    postComment();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way to do this using IME Options. This allows you to define a particular action that will replace the Enter key in the keyboard, without messing with handling key codes.

Update you layout XML to add the `imeOptions` attribute :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" />
```

Then, handle this specific event in your Java code :

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendMessage();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

You can find more details in the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action).

Comment: I tried at first and it didnt worked because I had `android:inputType="textMultiLine "` instead of just `text`. Now it all works perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Pixel XL (I presume it's running Android O), you can try replacing `setOnKeyListener` with `setOnEditorActionListener`:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) {
                postComment();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

You can take a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) for more information on why you should use `setOnEditorActionListener` instead of `setOnKeyListener`. Here's a short quote from the documentation describing why:

> You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targeting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targeting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software input methods may never send key events regardless of the version.

In essence, sending such events is discouraged. Use IME options.

Comment: Thanks for that, but thats exactly the same result as using setOnKeyListener

Comment: This actually breaks even the samsungs s7 version as well. Now this will not work as well